# Language Localisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, arabic-support

I am developing an application which supports 4 different languages. One of the language is Arabic. Used OpenSans font in whole application

I am getting below json response,

```
"card_description" = "\U00d9\U0160\U00d9\U2026\U00d9\U0192\U00d9\U2020\U00d9\U0192 \U00d8\U00b1\U00d9\U0192\U00d9\U02c6\U00d8\U00a8 \U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U201e\U00d8\U00af\U00d8\U00b1\U00d8\U00a7\U00d8\U00ac\U00d8\U00a9 \U00d9\U02c6\U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U201e\U00d8\U00aa\U00d9\U2020\U00d9\U201a\U00d9\U201e \U00d8\U00a8\U00d9\U2021\U00d8\U00a7 \U00d8\U00b9\U00d8\U00a8\U00d8\U00b1 \U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U201e\U00d9\U0192\U00d8\U00ab\U00d9\U0160\U00d8\U00b1 \U00d9\U2026\U00d9\U2020
\n\U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U201e\U00d9\U2026\U00d8\U00af\U00d9\U2020 \U00d9\U02c6\U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U201e\U00d8\U00a8\U00d9\U201e\U00d8\U00af\U00d8\U00a7\U00d8\U00aa \U00d9\U0081\U00d9\U0160 \U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U201e\U00d8\U00af\U00d8\U00a7\U00d9\U2020\U00d9\U2026\U00d8\U00a7\U00d8\U00b1\U00d9\U0192";
```

By converting it in UTF8String, my getting below result after running the application in simulator.

[image]

Used below code to display text in label,

```
[cell.btnDescription setTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[[arrCards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:wCARD_DESC] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I am not getting proper arabic language result.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do the following code for decrypting the arabic content.

```
[cell.btnDescription setTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[[arrCards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:wCARD_DESC] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The whole thing is coming from JSON and they will decode/encode that for you, I have faced the same problem with my arabic app, and What JSON developer did is  they add a header function i.e

1. `header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');`

and decode the value by this function below:

2. `html_entity_decode`

Follow the image below, it may help you.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't need to convert to UTFString. 
Just simply use like below code that one should use for other languages:

```html
[cell.btnDescription setTitle:[[arrCards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:wCARD_DESC] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And don't worry about JSON response Arabic text will be displayed like that only in log.